# Flutter log event with google analytics

Tags: android, flutter, dart, google-analytics, firebase-analytics

I have set up Google Analytics with in my flutter app. It all seems to be working as standard, with data coming through and being displayed on the analytics console screen, showing users, events count that sort of thing.

I see the default events are: user_engagement, screen_view, session_start, first_open, app_remove, app_clear_data.

These are all having event count data coming through fine. I want to set up my own custom event within the flutter app. I have tried this...

```
_sendAnalyticsEvent() async {
    FirebaseAnalytics analytics = FirebaseAnalytics();

    await analytics.logEvent(
      name: "save_plant",
      parameters: <String, dynamic>{
        'plant_name': currentPlant.name,
        'plant_species': currentPlant.species,
        'plant_group': currentPlant.group,
        'new_plant': widget.newPlant
      },
    );
  }
```

... but nothing seems to be coming through on the events. Am I missing something here with doing custom events with a flutter app? I have the google-services.json file correctly in the android app directory.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

When You log an event with `FirebaseAnalytics`, it takes **up to 24 hours** to get it available in the `Events` dashboard.

If You want to test "real time" logging, You should try the [Debug View (link)](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/debugview).

After You set it up *for a specific device* (there are two easy steps, [check it out here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/debugview#enabling_debug_mode)), You will see each event **only a few seconds** after You log it from Your app, in the `DebugView` section.

[image]

Comment: Can we use this type of view in the production environment?

Comment: @RajithaPerera not sure, it's been a long time since I used this. Anyways, I think it is easy to check it yourself.

Answer (score -1):

Update to 5.0.11, should resolve the issue

```
firebase_analytics: ^5.0.11
```